# How to match the closest opening and closing brackets

Tags: regex

I have the regex `[(\[].*?text.*?[)\]]`

I intend to match everything inside the bracket containing "text", including the brackets themselves, but not other sibling brackets. The brackets will not be nested.

With the text: [filler dontmatch filler] ( filler text filler)

[filler dontmatch filler] also gets matched.

However,
( filler text filler) [filler dontmatch filler] works as intended.

Something about regex working from left to right?

How do I make it work in both cases? I am using the java regex engine.

Edit: I don't care about balancing the same type of brackets, but the text and the closest brackets enclosing it should be matched.

Comment: Try excluding them with negated character classes, `[(\[][^()\[\]]*?text[^()\[\]]*[)\]]`

Comment: That seems to work (for some reason), Wiktor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
[(\[][^()\[\]]*?text[^()\[\]]*[)\]]
```

*Details*:

- `[(\[]` - a`(` or `[`
- `[^()\[\]]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(`, `)`, `[` and `]` as few as possible
- `text` - a word `text`
- `[^()\[\]]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`, `)`, `[` and `]` as many as possible
- `[)\]]` -  a `)` or `]` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h881Pt/1).

Comment: Why would you not use lazy star in the second negated character class too?

Comment: @hoshiKuzu There is no need as the negated character class does not match `)` and `]`. Lazy quantifier would make it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use two regex'es to match `()` or `[]`:

```
\[.*?text.*?\]|\(.*?text.*?\)
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/GQJw6b/1)

Comment: This will still match the whole thing in `(filler dontmatch filler) ( filler text filler)`